# How to generate a list easily with powers of 10?

Tags: r

I would like to generate a list easily with numbers 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1,10,100... Is there any way to do that easily?

Comment: As easy as `10^(-4:2)`.

Answer (score 2):

We could use R's vectorised operations

```
n <- 7 #No of terms required in final output
start <- 0.0001

start * 10 ^ (seq_len(n) - 1)
#[1]   0.0001   0.0010   0.0100   0.1000   1.0000  10.0000 100.0000
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
options("scipen"=-100, "digits"=4)
0.0001 * 10^(0:6)
# [1] 1e-04 1e-03 1e-02 1e-01 1e+00 1e+01 1e+02
```

OR, non-scientific:

```
options("scipen"=100, "digits"=4)
0.0001 * 10^(0:6)
# [1]   0.0001   0.0010   0.0100   0.1000   1.0000  10.0000 100.0000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apply(as.data.frame(-4:2),1,FUN = function(x) 10^x)

#[1] 1e-04 1e-03 1e-02 1e-01 1e+00 1e+01 1e+02
```

Or, as suggested in the comment:

```
10^(-4:2)
#[1] 1e-04 1e-03 1e-02 1e-01 1e+00 1e+01 1e+02
```